# Can I bring my personal electronic items to US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, electronic-items

I'm entering the USA in 10 days as a refugee, but I have concerns relating items that I can bring in to the US.
I've read the list of items that I can't bring in, but I think it might be a little different for me, because I hold an Iranian passport and I'm considered Iranian. (However, I've lived in Austria for the past few months and I'm going to US from there.)

For example, I have some electronic items (such as a router, a chip programmer, a bunch of cables) that I have used before for my work, but I think they may cause problems when entering.

But the thing is neither of those items fall under the prohibited items (and an American can bring in them without any issues).

Is that something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The US Treasury has [published guidelines](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/iran.pdf) regarding imports from Iran, which read as follows:

> IMPORTS FROM IRAN - Goods or services of Iranian origin may not 
>   be imported into the United States, either directly or through third 
>   countries, with the following exceptions:
>
> - a) Gifts valued at $100 or less;
> - b) Information and informational materials;
> - c) Household and personal effects, of persons arriving in the 
>     United States, that were actually used abroad by the 
>     importer or by other family members arriving from the same 
>     foreign household, that are not intended for any other person 
>     or for sale, and that are not otherwise prohibited from 
>     importation; and
> - d) Accompanied baggage for personal use normally incident to 
>     travel.

Since you state that your electronics are not otherwise controlled by US import regulations, you should be able to bring them into the US under exception (c) assuming you do not intend to sell them.

Please note these regulations apply only to goods manufactured or sold in Iran. As far as I am aware, there are no import regulations specifically pertaining to items of non-Iranian origin belonging to Iranian persons entering the US.

Comment: Thx for the answer. In fact, none if them have been made in Iran. They are products from US based or EU based companies like Cisco, Canon or ...